# Вызов jar или .class файла из java программы

Tags: jar, java, классы

1. Каким образом вызвать исполнение jar файла из java программы(т.е. из нее будет осуществляться вызов другой java программы)? (хотелось бы увидеть пример)
2. Каким образом вызвать исполнение class файла из java программы(т.е. из нее будет осуществляться вызов другой java программы)? (хотелось бы увидеть пример)

Answer (score 5):

Для исполнения любой внешней программы:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar A.jar");
```

ну и аналогично можно и класс исполнить.

Вариант 2:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "A.jar");
pb.directory(new File("/working/directory"));
Process proc = pb.start();
```

Comment: Ну это слишком общий пример. Для Java можно было бы обойтись другими средствами чем тяжелой артиллерией с системным `fork/exec`

Answer (score 3):

В том же процессе можно выполнить нужный метод нужного класса с помощью reflection. Ниже пример вызова статического метода main(String[] args).

```
    try {
        //Загружаем класс с именем className
        Class<?> targetClass = Class.forName(className);

        //Находим метод с именем "main" и списком параметров String[]
        Class[] argTypes = new Class[]{String[].class};
        Method mainMethod = targetClass.getDeclaredMethod("main", argTypes);

        //В качестве параметра передаем пустой массив
        Object[] arguments = new Object[]{new String[0]};
        mainMethod.invoke(null, arguments);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        //handle exception
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        //handle exception
    } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
        //handle exception
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
```

Comment: Такой способ мне больше нравится, так сказать более Java способ, чем тот который предложен @Nofate

Comment: @Nofate-у для личного использования тоже больше нравится. Минус в том, что класс должен быть в classpath.

Comment: @Nofate можно реализовать свой класслоадер.

Comment: само собой можно. но для того, чтобы просто запустить джарник это как-то жирновато, нет? )

Comment: @Nofate it depends :)

Comment: @Nofate: для `exec` `java` должен быть в `PATH`, так что ситуация симметрична.